# Body with head?

Tags: single-word-requests

when I talk about body, I always split the head from the body.  What word I can use a word that include my body with my head?

For example: The music is calling my body.

I want to mean my brain and head also enjoy the music, not just the body, not just the rhythm.

In computer language, they split up like /head>, /body>

Comment: Body: the whole physical structure that forms a person or animal. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/body -

Comment: You may use the expression “my whole body”.

Comment: So I have to express in order to mean the whole body. Come on, there must be a better noun for this.  This is our bodies. Everyone got the body,

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site :) ... can you clarify your question a little bit, please? Do you include arms and legs in your normal use of the word body? So not just the torso, but the whole physical organism except the head? When you say, "my brain and head also enjoy the music", do you mean your mind as well as your body, or only the physical organs of head and brain?

Comment: Hi , Thanks for the comment. I want to mean everything about my body and my head physically, virtually.   Should I use"I" to express? I love to see if you compare and contrast the word usage for the whole body physically and virtually. What if just my whole body with one virtual thing ,my mind, only. I really interested in studying how a human response to music. Thanks

Comment: Besides this, a whole body with the eye vision , or a whole body with 5 basic senses,how to call it? Thanks.

Comment: I agree with the first two comments: "body" covers your intended meaning, or "whole body" emphasises it. When a news report says a dead body was found somewhere, nobody (ha!) interprets that as meaning a headless corpse.  I don't think your point about computing terminology is relevant to the way people describe human bodies. Incidentally, our bodies have more than five basic senses.

Comment: The music is calling me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before suggesting some answers, I will note that the word body can be used in various ways. The comment by user067531 is correct: **body** can include the head. If someone wants to be clear that they are talking about the full body (with head), the most normal and common expression is ***"whole body"***. This corresponds to [sense 1) in this dictionary definition](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/body).

> **My whole body sways to the rhythm.**

However, you are correct that there is another sense of body, which excludes the head. This is [sense 3)](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/body) in the linked definition above.

> **The blow almost severed his head from his body.**

---

There are many other words that mean the whole physical/biological body of a person (including the head).  There are also many that refer to the whole person, including the physical body and thoughts, feelings, perceptions.

Some of these words make very subtle distinctions between different aspects of a human being. For example the word ***soma*** means

> [**The body as distinct from the soul, mind, or psyche.**](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3146208/)

Words like **physicality**, **corporeality** and **organism** can be used in a similar way.

If you mean that every part of you - physical and mental - is affected by the music, then you can just use the pronouns ***I*** or ***me*** without any extra explanation.

> **The music moved me.**

You could replace "me" in that sentence with one of these: **"my being"**; **"my whole self"**.

---

There are also various philosophical and scientific questions about how mind and body are connected, and the difference between the subjective experience of one's body and the objective experience of someone else's body (or your own body image), and so on... but those go beyond the remit of this website!

Comment: GOOD!    Thank you.  You save me from falling, thank you :)

Comment: I find a minor question about this. Can I call the whole body as "the mortal"?

Comment: It would be very unusual to describe the body as "the mortal". You can say that, but only if you believe that all the non-physical aspects of a person survive after death. Like, if you think that your personality, emotions and thoughts cannot die.

Comment: Thx.   I have another extra question for asking expert like you. I think the mortal can mean things between random and calculated,  any better word? Maybe it's interesting to see the relationship of a better word and the mortal are related. I want to learn more way to describe human. Hope you don't mind , thx

Comment: I don't understand that question, sorry! 'Mortal' as an adjective means 'something that can die', for example: "the gods are immortal, man is mortal". As a noun, ' a mortal' means a human or an animal, etc... anything that doesn't live forever.

Comment: All mortal,and all creature are being random and calculated. Can I take these feature( or quality) to highlight the mortal? Something Like philosophically friendly. So in future when I use this new word to mention human, everyone knows I am talking about the khaos of mortal. Not other aspect like economically. The human nature of mortal but philosophically friendly Thx :)

Comment: Maybe not one word, but a two-word phrase, Conditioned Being?

Comment: https://www.britannica.com/topic/condition-logic#ref48366

Comment: Thank you. what a good word!  I must have to give you a tick. Thank you for patient and effort. You made my day! I have nothing to ask, but can you provide a link that is about speical usage of term like the ones I have been questioning. It could be a good time saver for me this beginner. Thank you :)

Comment: No problem :) If you are a beginner, this site for learners is better https://ell.stackexchange.com/